# How to generate a image of uiscrollview?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with subview like `UILable` and webviews. So when I click on a button  all the content of the scrollveiw should generate as a image. I tried to generate it but it is not getting all the content of `UIScrollView` it is just showing only visible view.

and my code is

```
[Scroll.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Comment: it's because you are getting only current context of UIGraphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `scrollView's` contentSize is larger but its `scrollView.frame` is still smaller.

Instead of `scrollview`, add your content first into a `UIView` (Let say it `containerView`). `containerView` should have height-width stretchable according to your content.

After that add your `containerView` to `scrollView`. So your `scrollView` require `contentSize = containerView.frame.size`

Now try to taking screenshot for the `IBOutlet` of `containerView`, not the `scrollView`.

I have not tried this out, but I guess it should work in this case.